# jQuery AJAX Web service works only locally

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a simple ASP.NET Web Service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string SetName(string name) {
        return "hello my dear friend " + name;

    }
}
```

For this Web Service I created Virtual Directory, so I can receive the access by taping 
http://localhost:89/Service.asmx.

I try to call it via simple html page with jQuery. For this purpose I use function

```
CallWS() {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: "{'name':'Pumba'}",
             dataType: "json",
             url: "http://localhost:89/Service.asmx/SetName",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (msg) {
                 $('#DIVid').html(msg.d);

             },
             error: function (e) {
                 $('#DIVid').html("Error");
             }
         });
```

The most interesting fact: If I create the html page in the project with my WebService and change url to Service.asmx/SetName everything works excellent.
But if I try to call this webservice remotely - success function works but msg is null.

After that I tried to call this service even via SOAP. It is the the same - locally it works excellent, but remotely - not at all.

```
  var ServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:89/Service.asmx?op=SetName'; 

  function beginSetName(Name) {
      var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Body> <SetName xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> <name>' + Name + '</name> </SetName> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>';
      $.ajax({
          url: ServiceUrl,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "xml",
          data: soapMessage,
          complete: endSetName,
          contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
      });

      return false;
  }

function endSetName(xmlHttpRequest, status)
{
    $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
    .find('SetNameResult')
    .each(function () {
        var name = $(this).text();
        alert(name);
    });
 }
```

In this case status has value "parseerror".
Could you please help me to resolve this problem? What should I do to call another WebService remotely by url via jQuery.

Thank you in advance,
Greg

Comment: This has got to be one of the most frequently-asked questions here. You cannot use XMLHttpRequest to make requests to a domain different than the domain your page came from.

Comment: So what solution can be in this situation?

Comment: The problem is that I need to create SideBar Gadget and it is necessary to use the webservice... That's why it is so necessary to use such architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you will need to modify your AJAX to use JSONP instead of JSON.  Check out the [jQuery Cross-Domain Ajax Guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide).

Comment: For this I need to modify the existing WebService, but originally I need to use another webservice and there won't be access to change it.

Comment: @Greg Unfortunately, you won't be able to talk to that original web service directly using AJAX due to the same origin policy.  This is an important security feature in JavaScript.  You will need to either create a new web service that returns the same data as the original but using jsonp or (and this is kind of a kludge...I don't recommend it if you can avoid it) create a new web service that talks to the original web service and returns the results as jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

Pointy is correct, but to solve this you need to expose an endpoint that is callable from outside the application.

I suggest you take a look at creating JSON web services using WCF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to use the existing ASP.NET web service, which is more complicated than this one. So I've just created this one for this example.